# Saving data to a .json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to store data from a html form to .json file, but instead i'm getting this:

http://localhost:3000/teachers/create?avatar_url=&name=&birth=&grade=medio&class_type=P&lesson=

Javascript code for this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const data = require("./data.json");

exports.post = function (req, res) {
    const keys = Object.keys(req.body);

    for (key of keys) {
        if (req.body[key] == "") {
            return res.send("Please, fill in all fields!");
        }
    }

    let { avatar_url, birth, name, grade, class_type, lesson } = req.body;

    birth = Date.parse(birth);
    const created_at = Date.now();
    const id = Number(data.teachers.length + 1);

    data.teachers.push({
        id,
        name,
        avatar_url,
        birth,
        grade,
        class_type,
        lesson,
        created_at,
    });

    fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function (err) {
        if (err) return res.send("Write file error!");

        return res.redirect("/teachers");
    });

    //return res.send(req.body);
};
```

Comment: so what is your problem? can you describe more  what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to insert a name, birth date, etc in a form and save the data into that data.json, then return to /teachers page, but instead the keys are showing in the url address and not being saved in the json file.

Comment: Something is wrong with however you are trying to create the HTTP request, but you haven't shown us that code, so we can't tell what.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without seeing your code, but my guess based on your question is that your html `<form>` doesn't have `method="post"`, so it's submitting as a GET. That would account for why you're seeing the params in the URL query string, and why your handler—which appears to be set up for POST requests—isn't doing what you expect, because that handler isn't receiving this request.

Comment: Thank you for you attention. You are correct, that's what i forgot to put on my code.